# Why won't my game instantiate?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I don't know why the Insantiation doesn't work. I'm trying to do it with the space bar. Or could it be something about the axis?

```
public GameObject projectile;
public Transform padre, hijo;
public Rigidbody r;
private float value;

void Start () {
    padre = transform.parent;
    hijo = transform.GetChild (0);
    value = 0;
}

void Update () {

    float j = Input.GetAxis ("Jump");
    if (j == 1 && value == 0) {
        Instantiate (projectile, hijo.position, hijo.transform.rotation);
    }

    float h = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal2");
    r.transform.Translate (h * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);

    float v = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical2");
    padre.Rotate (0, 0, -v * Time.deltaTime * 20);

    value = j;
}
```

Comment: Be sure that you are holding space long enough. `GetAxis` will by default not return 1 immediatly when pressed, it smoothes out the value.

Comment: you could try `if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){ j = 1 }` if you want to check if space was clicked on that frame. Or use GetAxisRaw if you don't want the smoothing.

Answer (score 2):

Comparing float is never a good idea.

The `j` variable  must equal `1` and `value` variable must be `0` before that if statement becomes true. `Input.GetAxis` returns values between `0` and `1`.

If all you want to do is instantiate a GameObject when the Space key is pressed they simply use `Input.GetKeyDown` instead of `Input.GetAxis`

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    Instantiate(projectile, hijo.position, hijo.transform.rotation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking j to exactly equal 1. However, getAxis returns a float that will be close, but not exactly equal to 1. Instead check for when j is close enough to 1.

For instance (pseudocode):

```
float j = Input.GetAxis ("Jump");
float ep=.1f;
if (Math.abs(j-1)<ep && value == 0) {
   //Instantiate
```

Also, you should make sure that `value` is in fact equal to 0 (You might have some other code modifying it beyond whats shown)